# Как с помощью python скачать файл с Google drive?

Tags: python, python-2.x, google-drive

Хочу реализовать программу с автообновлением, а для этого нужно чтобы скрипт скачивал файл с Google Drive. Сразу говорю что файл находится в открытом для чтения и скачивания доступе. Но как это сделать если не получается получить ссылку на сам файл, поэтому я и не знаю как это реализовать.

Comment: а что, если пробовать парсить ссылку, используя [`WebDriver`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)? Если я правильно понимаю суть проблемы.

Comment: @approximatenumber, а модуль PyDrive для моей задачи сойдёт?

Comment: Изи. Могу скинуть код, если вопрос еще актуален (2 года прошло)

Comment: @МихаилМуратов, да, ответ на мой вопрос может пригодиться другим.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import urllib.request
logo = urllib.request.urlopen("https://drive.google.com/........download").read()
f = open("имя файла с расширением", "wb")
f.write(logo)
f.close()
```

Могу дать наглядный пример:

```
import urllib.request
logo = urllib.request.urlopen("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1gkTOtZ7K72IxxTQ8W1bHMmLglvAYUfIe&export=download").read()
f = open("photo.jpg", "wb")
f.write(logo)
f.close()
```

Но чтобы получить такую ссылку, заканчивающюся на download, нужно сначала перейти по ссылке, указанной для общего доступа, а потом нажать на значок загрузки. И открывшаяся ссылка, собственно, будет заканчиваться на download, а это как раз то что нам и было нужно. А потом просто копируем её в вставляем.

Comment: Можете добавить и вариант для Python 2?

Comment: Увы, нет. Я в 3 питоне разбираюсь то не сильно, а со вторым не знаком тем более. Так что здесь помочь уже никак ее смогу

Answer (score 2):

У сервиса Google Drive есть собственный [RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk). Через него можно получать данные о файле и скачивать его.